# Inserting complex dictionaries into a sqlite database?

Tags: python, sqlite, dictionary

I have a dictionary that follows the following structure:

```
mydict = {0: {10001: {'simple': 1, 'example': 2}, 10002: {'simple': 2, 'example': 1}}, 1: {20002: {'simple': 0, 'example': 2}}}
```

The top-level key has no relation to the sqlite db, however the 10001, 10002, 20002 keys all represent primary keys in the same table, with their attached dictionaries containing attributes to also be inserted. The method I have come up with:

```
top_level_keys = mydict.keys()
list_of_lists = []    
for key in top_level_keys:
    primary_keys = mydict[key].keys()
    for k in primary_keys:    
        list_of_lists.append([k, mydict[key][k]["example"],mydict[key][k]["simple"]])
```

This gives me a list of all records in the order I need for a simple insert:

```
[[10001, 2, 1], [10002, 1, 2], [20002, 2, 0]]
```

The more columns that are added to the table however, the longer that *list_of_lists.append...* statement becomes - it's around 30 at the moment. I could iterate through those keys as well, but would then lose the ordering for the sqlite insert.

Is there a simpler/better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could specify your keys/order ahead of time as a list:

```
my_ordered_fields = ['example','simple'] #or ['example','simple','next','more next','..etc..']
```

Also note you can condense your code by simply iterating over the keys directly instead of declaring their values.

```
list_of_lists = []    
for key in mydict.keys():
    for k in mydict[key].keys():
        this_entry = [k]
        for ordered_field in my_ordered_fields:
            this_entry.append(mydict[key][k][ordered_field])   
        list_of_lists.append(this_entry)
```

It will be hard to simplify it much more than this, since if you want your fields returned in a certain order you will always have to specify their names and orders in *some* way.

You could also use some list comprehensions if want to condense the code a bit, though it **definitely** comes at the cost of readability/transparency.

```
sub_dicts = [lower_dict for lower_dict in mydict.values()]
list_of_lists = [[[lower_key]+[lower_dict[my_field] for my_field in my_ordered_fields] for lower_key,lower_dict in sub_dict.items()] for sub_dict in sub_dicts]
```

Comment: Thanks, I spent far too long trying to find a clever means to sort when the answer was a simple list!